Movie's name where arrow strikes girl's boobs?
What's the movie's name where a dwarf or something is a sharpshooter and an arrow strikes the girl's boobs and one hits the eye. Actually, the arrow goes right through the girl's nipples. The dwarf also eats the eye out of the arrow end. I remember that in the movie a few boys and girls go to some waterside jungle resort for a nice time and all this happens. 
The movie had the following properties that I remember:
Language: English
Country: USA

We're going to need a lot more information than this, what year, country and language was the film in, was it black and white or colour, did you see it on TV or a cinema, and when? By 'eye' do you mean the centre of her breast or her actual eye, and are we talking about fantasy dwarves or short people?

@CrowTRobot Added as much I could remember.

I'm an American (blame my parents) and I missed a memo. When did Hollywood become a country? And dang it, will I need a passport to visit or move there now?

This is the fate of Sophie in the horror film Wrong Turn 3 from 2009. The villain Three Fingers (who has a kind of elfish face) kills her in the exact grisly way you've described. There are some graphic pictures of it on this page, and you can see a bit of it in this trailer around 0:13 (both links NSFW).

This video is NSFW for where I work.

Good point. Linked instead & warning added.
